# How can I use google cloud platform as a private customer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I go to https://console.developers.google.com I can't use any of the products. I'm always forced to start a free trial (300$). However, the description contains the restriction that *"this service can only be used for business or commercial reasons".* Does this mean you cannot use google cloud platform as a private customer?

Comment: For this question open a case with the Cloud billing team: https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing

Comment: @S1lentSt0rm new answer was posted here, revise your selection.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I understand from Google's [support page here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6090602), they suggest you to stop using their services if you are a citizen of a EU country which has VAT and if you do not intend to use Google services for economical benefit.

I hoped that Google would offer their Nearline Storage for "average customers" to store data backups but, alas...

Comment: If I select United state (I"m from europe) I can pick individual, does that change anything ?

Comment: @Ced Yes, that might be doable, but it feels like cheating and there is a risk that at some point Google might detect that I'm not from the USA and block the account.

Comment: @Ced see my answer with application. The idea is that individuals still can use the platform. Business have the right the get non VAT invoice. Don't take this as something that stops you using a service. It's just accounting is different for private and businesses, and now it's clear when and how VAT is applied.

Comment: It seems, they have recently changed not only the documentation, but also the application form, so now EU citizens have Individual option available without any restrictions. But Russians are still in the same boat the EU citizens were some time ago.

Answer (score 42):

In January 2018, they updated the billing documentation VAT application for EU.

This page provides information on value-added tax (VAT) for Google Cloud Platform customers with European Union (EU) and Russian billing addresses.

https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/vat-overview

**Setup:**

During Google Cloud Platform billing setup, you select your Account type: `Business` or `Individual`.

Selecting `Business` means that you see a potential economic benefit from your development activities. For example, using Google Cloud Platform to develop prototypes or applications with a goal of generating revenue now or in the future. Most customers use Google Cloud Platform for business purposes.

**Business accounts in EU or Russia**

- Non-Irish customers — We won't add VAT charges to your account. You're responsible for determining taxes due at your country's local rate.
- Irish customers — We'll be adding VAT to your charges.

**Individual accounts in EU**

Your account is subject to standard VAT charges in the country where you’re located. We'll automatically add VAT to invoices for your Google Cloud Platform use.

> We reserve the right to change account type to Business if we find
>   that you're using your account for business purposes.

**Individual accounts in Russia**

In Russia, Google Cloud Platform services can be used only for business purposes.

Comment: @S1lentSt0rm, please consider to mark this answer as "best".

Comment: Why does Google treat Russia in such a special way? :(

Comment: @ivan Actually russian laws doesn't let certain companies to offer services for individual purposes. Always the issue is on the home country of the end-user.

Comment: @Pentium10 thanks for this answer, my google cloud server is deployed in India and it's not working in Russia, my account type is "Business". whats problem?

Comment: Also, Google Cloud Platform isn't accepting my Russian cards in the billing section even after I registered "Business" as my account type.. So, basically, I can't use google services or what?

Comment: Yandex Maps API was free for getting a static map which i wanted.. so if you are having problems, just use Yandex Maps API https://yandex.com/dev/maps/staticapi/doc/1.x/dg/concepts/input_params.html/

Comment: "In Russia, Google Cloud Platform services can be used only for business purposes"... But why?

Comment: Taxation and respecting the law is the answer.